# Wordpress theme not showing google ad in sidebar

Tags: wordpress, adsense

I am using the pixel theme in wordpress.  when i try to add my ad to the sidebar it does not show.  I have it on the site now [my site](https://thesneakerthirst.com/)

Here is the code is inside of a widget:

```
<div id='simple_adsense_widget'><script type="text/javascript">
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-1097285086262410";
    /* ST */
    google_ad_slot = "4084760340";
    google_ad_width = 728;
    google_ad_height = 90;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script></div></div></li></ul>
```

any ideas?

Comment: The code appears valid, and does not throw errors.  Have you checked your ad_client number? [Google has some FAQ](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=10036) about ads not showing up.  Finally, when I view your site there are javascript errors thrown by your twitter plugin/functionality, which may be preventing the google adsense from running properly.

Comment: fixed. had the wrong email so my codes were not vaild

Answer (score 1):

Your ad seems to be shown correctly. Sometimes Google doesn't deliver ads when there's not enough bidding or when it recognises that the visitor is the ad host.

I am shown very few ads on my own blog while editing.

Comment: hey thanks i fixed the error...wholetime my email was wrong thanks!

Comment: hey @user1013905, can you please tell me how you fixed this? I am experiencing same :( my sidebar is not showing adsense ads on my site => www.techforbe.com